# Retrieve post parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile

Newbie question.

Found that most of tutorials in the Internet focused how to pass parameters by GET / POST.
Just some of them pointed to retrieval data and mostly by using PHP (jQuery docs) / ASP.NET etc.

How to retrieve AJAX posted data using pure JavaScript?

Exactly:

Post:

```
function detailOperator(_recordId, _title) {
   $.mobile.changePage('#operator-view', 
     { dataUrl: '?ID=' + _recordId + '&title=' + _title});
}
```

Post changing page successfully.

How to retrieve ID and title in operator-view page?

Comment: Go to my other article: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600 and search chapter: Data/Parameters manipulation between page transitions. You will find several solutions to your need.

Answer (score 4):

POST data *cannot* be obtained by client side scripts, unless the server side script handing the POST request sends it back to the client with the response. In short, there is no built-in way of doing this.

However, your server side script can choose to *pass* the POST data back to the client via cookies or hidden variables and then your client side JavaScript can access the values therein.

Comment: +1 for an answer but it doesn't have anything to do with this questions.

Answer (score 1):

What finally I've got (commented Jim' idea):

Pass parameters:

```
function detailOperator(_recordId) {
    $.mobile.changePage('#operator-view', { dataUrl: '?ID=' + _recordId });
    // Below not working (no errors) - maybe this sample working for external pages?
    //$.mobile.changePage('#operator-view', { dataUrl : '?ID=' + _recordId, data : { 'ID' : _recordId }, reloadPage : true, changeHash : true });
}
```

so, here the same as it was.

Retrieve parameters:

```
// Below not working (no errors) because of empty "url"
/*
var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
var _recordId = parameters.replace('ID=', '');
*/
var parameters = location.hash.substring(2).split("&");
var _recordId = parameters[0].replace('ID=', '');
```

Thanks a lot for patience!

Comment: You probably should mark this then as your accepted answer, you can do so by ticking off the hollow check-mark to the left of this answer.

Comment: StackOverflow allows to accept own answer in 2 days - not earlier :-(

Answer (score 0):

POST values are not accessible client side.
GET values can be accessed via

```
window.location.search
```

Comment: Thanks, Jim.
But I found that `$('#operator-modify').live('pageshow', function(event, ui) { alert(location.search); });` show empty string.
Does it mean wrong call of $.mobile.changePage ?

Comment: I never really used jquery mobile, i wanted to post my answer in a comment but i don't got enough rep for that. But as Gajotres says: Go to my other article: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600) and search chapter: Data/Parameters manipulation between page transitions. You will find several solutions to your need.

Comment: @user1895410 just a note as of jQuery 1.7 [.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated in favor of [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)